# DataStax Spark Cassandra Connector fails to connect when mixing contact points across regions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

At least this is what it appears to be. I can list any number of East or West coast machines, and it only seems to break when they're mixed.

I'm using the latest (1.6.0-M2) [DataStax Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md#cassandra-connection-parameters) with Apache Spark (1.6.1). I have a single contact point currently, and wanted to add a few more nodes for failover. The documentation was recently updated to state that comma delimited lists are supported. If I list hosts from both my West & East coast data centers, I get a similar error:

> java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at
>   {10.240.0.11, 10.240.0.12, 10.240.0.9, 10.240.0.8, 10.240.0.7,
>   10.240.0.10}:9042

Is this some artifact of the drivers' preference toward the local datacenter? Can I not configure it for full failover? Should I be careful to only supply a couple contact points in a single region?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is embarrassing. I didn't read all of the error messages:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Contact points contain
>   multiple data centers: us-central1, us-east1

It's an odd behavior, but what I already suspected.